# Evaluate $\int_{\delta S} w$ where $w = (x + y)dz + (y + z)dx + (x + z)dy$ and $S$ is the upper part of the unit sphere

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms

**Problem:**

> Let $w = (x + y)dz + (y + z)dx + (x + z)dy$ and let $S$ be the upper part of the unit sphere; that is, $S$ is the set of $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2 =1$ and $z\ge0$. $\delta$$S$ is the unit circle in the $xy$ plane. Evaluate $\int_{\delta S} w$ both directly and by Stokes' theorem.

**Attempt:**
So to evaluate directly, I evaluated ${dw}$ and got $dx$^$dz$ + $dy$^$dz$ + $dy$^$dx$ + $dz$^$dx$ + $dx$^$dy$ + $dz$^$dy$ which I'm pretty sure equals 0. Therefore $\int_{\delta S} w$ = $\int_S dw$ = 0.

But how do I evaluate this using Stokes' theorem: $\int\int_S \Delta\times F \cdot dS = \int_{\delta S} F \cdot ds $?

Also is what I did above correct?

Comment: I don't have the time to go into a full answer right now, but as a few pointers/comments: I believe your first attempt would be considered as evaluating the integral utilizing the Stokes theorem (that is what you did, after-all!). To evaluate the integral directly, what you need to do is actually compute the integral $$ \int_{\partial S} w $$ directly without using the Stoke's theorem. You should be able to do this by perhaps parametrizing the unit circle in the xy plane, and noticing that on $\partial S$, $z = 0$? Just a quick thought, sorry for the lack of detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to evaluate $\int_{\partial S} w$ using Stokes Theorem, it is enough to compute that $\mathrm{d} w = 0$, and so on $S$
$$
\int_{\partial S} w = \int_S \mathrm{d} w = 0.
$$
Fairly straightforward.
For the second part, evaluating the integral directly, we find that 
$$
\int_{\partial S} w = \int_{x^2 + y^2 = 1} (x + y)\mathrm{d}z + (y + z)\mathrm{d}x + (x + z)\mathrm{d}y .
$$
Noting that on $\partial S$ $z = \mathrm{d} z = 0$, we can simplify this to the form 
$$
\int_{x^2 + y^2 = 1} y \mathrm{d} x + x \mathrm{d} y = \int_{0} ^{2 \pi} \sin \theta \cdot (- \sin \theta ) + \cos \theta \cdot (\cos \theta ) \, \mathrm{d} \theta .
$$
This integral of course can be computed - however, lets think about this for a moment: cosine and sine are periodically equivalent in the sense that $\sin \theta = \cos (\theta - \frac{\pi}{2})$. So it is obvious and straightforward that 
$$
\int_{0} ^{2 \pi} \sin ^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d} \theta
=
\int_{0} ^{2 \pi} \cos ^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d} \theta
$$
from which it follows that 
$$
\int_{\partial S} w = 0.
$$

Comment: can one expedite the last part by noticing it is a circuit integral of the exact differential $ydx+xdy = d(xy)$?

Comment: Yes, that would be a more elegant way of performing the computation by far.